No Duplicate Posts with "Random" Query Loop
On my Wordpress site, I have a CSS grid. In the grid are several blocks that each use query loops to pull post titles, etc. The query loops are set to order by random. However, I get duplicate posts in the grid when I select random. What would be the best method to ensure I don't get any duplicate posts in the grid?
I've tried all kinds of code, arrays, transients, but I must be the worst because nothing I've tried works. I don't even know what method is best or if I should abandon this idea altogether.
This was the last query loop I tried:
$excluded_ids = get_transient('excluded_post_ids');// Query argumentsreturn $args = array(    'post_type'      => 'post',    'posts_per_page' => 1,    'orderby'        => 'rand',    'post__not_in'   => $excluded_ids // Exclude already displayed posts);$query = new WP_Query($args);if ($query->have_posts()) {    while ($query->have_posts()) {        $query->the_post();        the_content();    }}wp_reset_postdata();

These are the PHP I tried:
<?php// Get the list of excluded post IDs from a transient$excluded_ids = get_transient('excluded_post_ids');// If transient doesn't exist, initialize as an empty arrayif ($excluded_ids === false) {    $excluded_ids = array();}?>

<?php// Function to initialize and fetch unique post IDsfunction initialize_and_fetch_posts() {    // Get excluded post IDs    $excluded_ids = get_transient('excluded_post_ids');    if ($excluded_ids === false) {        $excluded_ids = array();    }    $block_queries = array();    // Loop through each block    for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {        $query_args = array(            'post_type'        => 'post',            'posts_per_page'   => 1,            'fields'           => 'ids',            'post__not_in'     => $excluded_ids, // Exclude already displayed posts            'orderby'          => 'rand'        );        $query = new WP_Query($query_args);        // Add current post IDs to excluded list        $excluded_ids = array_merge($excluded_ids, $query->posts);        $block_queries[$i] = $query->posts;    }    // Store updated excluded IDs in transient    set_transient('excluded_post_ids', $excluded_ids, 6);    return $block_queries;}?>


Please format the php. What debugging have you tried? For example have you used var_dump to see what is in that array?

Either make just one query to begin with (just because you want to put the posts into different locations in your grid, doesn't necessarily mean each "location" needs its own, separate query); or seed the random generator with a start value (as long as the start value stays the same, it will also create the same sequence of random numbers), and combine that with offset/pagination parameters, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/274163
